# URL polling as a simple streaming mechanism in Matlab (or in general)

Tags: matlab, url, streaming

I would like to stream images between two computers by storing the images on one computer and reading them over the internet as a URL on another computer using Matlabs `imread` function.

I am currently doing this by creating a stream of png images from a webcam on one of the computers. This is connected to a network drive which is available through a public webadress.

On the other computer I am simply running a loop as such:

```
while 1
 I = imread('http://mywebaddress.blah/image.png');
 imshow(I);
 drawnow
end
```

The problem is that this works for about 3 or 4 frames and then crashes Matlab. It doesnt throw an exception, it simply crashes.

Im guessing this is because there is a synchronization error which isnt being accounted for in Matlab's imread code for URL based images. So I guess that if the image is only half available when being streamed and it stops being available because its been overwritten on the other side then Matlab hasnt accounted for this and it bombs.

I need a simple mechanism for synchronization. The second computer can only read information. It cannot send information. Clearly synchronization wont be perfect but Id like a method which will result in absolutely minimal crashing... does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to solve this problem at the server side. I could see how you can have, say, the 10 most recent images named `image00.png` through `image09.png`. Now instead of overwriting the image that's currently being served up, you could instead serve up the "currentImage.png" which is a link that points to the most recent image. You update the link whenever a new image is created, and now you have 10x longer to read the image before it gets overwritten. Obviously you can create a deeper 'buffer' depending on the frequency with which you are updating the images, and the latency of reading.

If this isn't clear let me know and I can try to elaborate.

Comment: This is what Ive been planning on doing but I was wondering whether there might be a way to augment this using timestamps.